# Implementing image chroma keying with FIR filter in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab

Is there any way I can apply the concept of FIR filters in chroma key composition, where I will remove a green background to focus on a subject and replace a different image on the removed part, sort of like how they impose graphics on weather reports? If so, how can I implement it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

No, chroma keying and FIR filters are unrelated concepts.

Answer (score -1):

FIR is not a direct method to do chroma keying. Yet, it is hardly related. But let me give you an algorithm to perform a basic idea:

During the training stage:

1. Take a set of training images and for each set of image obtain the RGB histogram.
2. Merge the histograms into a single one by simply addition.
3. Fit a minimum enclosing volume ellipsoid to the "marked" voxels in the 3D histogram. This will be your "keying" model. It will then used in the estimation stage (Check below) Use Kachiyan's algorithm. A sample implementation is here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542-minimum-volume-enclosing-ellipsoid
4. Enlarge your ellipsoid a little bit to account for unseen data.

After having the ellipsoid, you are left with segmenting out the object from the green screen. Do that as follows:

`For each pixel in the new input image, check whether the pixels RGB values fall inside the ellipsoid. If it is inside the ellipsoid obtained at stage (3), it belongs to background. If it lies outside of the ellipsoid (4), it is in the foreground. If it lies in between, the foreground and background should be combined using a linearly implemented alpha mapping.`

To compute the distance to the ellipsoid, use Mahalanobis distance.

Please see this work (3D Keying) :
http://www.tzi.de/tzikeyer/keying_report.pdf

Comment: Hi, Are you the developed of TZI Keyer?

Comment: : ) No, I'm not. If you downvote this answer, please let me know why.

Comment: Hi, I didn't actually I will +1 it. Thank You.